# Selenium WebDriver C# Visual Studio N Unit Test Name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, webdriver, nunit

I am new to using Selenium WebDriver in C# on Visual Studio and am wondering if there is a comparable way to name a test like there is using Java and TestNG. For example in Java I have my test

```
@Test
public void SomeTest(){}
```

Instead of calling my Test Name "SomeTest" I can convert TestNG into XML and call my Test Name something more descriptive using the tag

```
    <test name = "blah blah">
    </test> "
```

Is there a similar parallel way to do this using C# N Unit testing in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# you can name your test method whatever you like. It can be as descriptive as you wish and if that is not enough you can use [NUnit's Description attribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=description&r=2.4.8) to add more meaningful text to your test method.